# How to calculate multiple columns in one Hoc view?

Tags: jasperserver

I am using `TIBCO Jaspersoft : Ad Hoc Editor` to create a `Hoc view`, where I have to calculate some column and generate reports.

I have `data source` where I have two `data sets`.

1. I have `MasterId,MasterName`
2. I have multiple record corresponding to MasterId. Ex. `ActivityId,Name,Type,StartTime,EndTime,MasterId (FK from MasterTable.MasterId)`

I have to calculate a column `1stActivity-Delay-hours`, where I have to show the difference between 2 dates in `HH:MM format (12:39)`

for that I have used `create calculated field option` and place the formula

```
ElapsedMinutes("EndTime", "StartTime")/60
```

and to filter the data I have created new `measure` too and place the formula like-

```
tblActivity.StartTime < 12-12-2017 1:10 and  tblActivity.EndTime > 11-12-2017 2:20
```

its working fine and showing the correct output except the `HH:MM` format. For example its showing `24.65` and instead `24.35` or something like that. I try to use `% (mod)` to get the minutes but `%` works as percentage here So I am not able to use the `MOD` functionality here **(1st issue)**

But when I need my second column in the same view with different condition (filter) for example:  `tblActivity.StartTime > 12-12-2017 1:10 and  tblActivity.EndTime < 11-12-2017 2:20`

and `Activity.Name='act1'` it will mess up with **1st column calculation**.

As per my understanding we can only have one `data-source` per `view`, and we can't merge multiple view with different `data-source`. 
can anybody suggest me how can I achieve this? how can I add multiple `data-source` in single view.

I can do this calculation in `SQL` easily by using `temp table`(#table). For instance I will calculate the `1stActivityDelay` column and store the `delay-hours` in `temp table` and then calculate the `2ndActivity` delay hours with different `where` condition and again store it in the `temp table` and at the end I will `select` the `rows` from `temp table`. But in this tool I am not able to find any way to do this.

Comment: @mdahlman can you help me here?

Comment: @Ankush Chhabra dude, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: my apologies, ok